# resque, resque-scheduler NoMethodError (undefined method `rpush' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I'm using resque-scheduler succefully on my dev machine, but once deployed I get this issue

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `rpush' for nil:NilClass)
```

when the process hits the line

```
Resque.enqueue_at(my_delay, my_worker,my_param)
```

I've runned bundle install and running resque 1.17.1 and resque-scheduler-2.0.0.d

any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ended up to be a configuration issue. The environment used wasn't specified in the resque config file...oops.